# Циклы в Python, как сделать цикл в/с request?

Tags: python

Доброго времени суток! Есть следующий код:

```
for i in json_data['data']:
 if i['user'] == 'user':
  time = (i['dur'])
  start_time= (i['start'])
  task = (i['task'])
  client = (i['client'])
  project = (i['project'])
  description = (i['description'])
  d = (xtemptime/1000)
  hours, remainder = divmod(d, 3600)
  minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
  hh = ("%d" % (hours))
  mm = ("%d" % (minutes))
  request = u"""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Insert xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <workdate>{start_time}</workdate>
      <customer>{client}</customer>
      <project>{project}</project>
      <workname>{description}</workname>
      <hours>{hh}</hours>
      <minutes>{mm}</minutes>
      <comments></comments>
      <worktype>1</worktype>
    </Insert>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>""".format(start_time=start_time, client=client, project=project, description=description, hh=hh, mm=mm)

encoded_request = request.encode('utf-8')

authenticationHeader = {
    "Host": "host",
    "Content-Type": "text/xml; charset=UTF-8",
    "Content-Length": len(encoded_request)
}

response = requests.post(url="http:url",
                         auth=HttpNtlmAuth('',''),
                         headers = authenticationHeader,
                         data = encoded_request,
                         verify=False)
```

Все данные берутся из `json_data = r.json()` который выше и вобщем с ним все хорошо.

Цикл `(for i in json_data['data']:)` отлично работает когда на вход ему приходит несколько записей, но вот в `request = u"""...` попадает только одна запись (последняя).

Пример того как это выглядит сейчас (если расставить `print i` и `print request` ):

```
~]# python test.py
(1800000, u'2016-09-10T12:00:00+03:00', None, u'test2', u'test2', u'test2')
(24296000, u'2016-09-10T11:35:44+03:00', None, u'test', u'test', u'test')
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Insert xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <workdate>2016-09-10T11:35:44+03:00</workdate>
      <customer>test</customer>
      <project>test</project>
      <workname>test</workname>
      <hours>1</hours>
      <minutes>1</minutes>
      <comments></comments>
      <worktype>1</worktype>
    </Insert>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
~]#
```

Как сделать, чтобы в `request = u"""..`. попадали все записи проходящие через цикл  for, и чтобы потом `requests.post` их отсылал? Как видно, то что относится к `test2` не попало в `request`.

Может я вообще иду не в том направлении, и лучше сделать как-то иначе?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Код делает именно то, что в нём написали.
У вас на каждом витке цикла переменная request перезаписывается новым значением. А нужно к тому, что туда уже попало на предыдущих витках, дописывать новую информацию.

Нужно до начала цикла объявить request, записав туда тот общий заголовок, который будет только один и не зависит от числа элементов:

```
request = u"""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>"""
```

(Я не знаю, должен ли следующий за этим тег быть общим для всех элементов, или для каждого индивидуальный - это вы уж сами посмотрите и добавьте его либо сюда, либо внутри цикла)

Внутри цикла вы дописываете в эту переменную то значение, которое будет отдельным для каждого элемента.

```
request += u"""здесь_какой_то_xml_код"""
```

Обратите внимание, что мы здесь используем не просто символ "равно", а комбинацию "плюс-равно" - это позволяет нам не затирать старое значение, а дописать к нему новое.

В случае необходимости уже после цикла нужно дописать в эту переменную ещё общую закрывающую часть запроса, если она есть.

NB: На самом деле, здесь правильнее использовать не +=, а конкатенацию через join, но я боюсь, что для вас это будет сложновато, и вообще это отдельная тема.
В вашем случае большой потери в производительности быть не должно, можно использовать +=

Comment: Да действительно, теперь все попадает `requests`, это здорово. Но как в таком случае, добиться того, чтобы при отправке (requests post) записи отправлялись по очереди, а не в одной?

Comment: Если нужно, чтобы они уходили по одному, то вы изначально поставили неправильно задачу. Получается, вам и не нужно накапливать все реквесты в одной переменной. Делайте их в цикле так, как у вас изначально и было, с тем отличием, что отсылать их нужно сразу же, не выходя из цикла. А вот ответы сервера (если они  вам нужны) уже придётся как-то накапливать, чтобы потом обработать.

Comment: Вы абсолютно правы, извиняюсь за неточность в постановке. Сделал без выхода из цикла, и все получилось.

Comment: @sirinzarin в общем случае, когда ближе с языком познакомитесь, вы можете также генерировать xml, используя объекты (такие как `xml.etree.ElementTree`), а не из строк собирать, что легко к ошибкам ведёт. Хотя, если приходится с soap работать (мои соболезнования), где часто сервер, в выбранном стеке,  понимает только весьма специфичный магический формат, то создание xml форматированием строкового шаблона может быть практичной идеей.